# react-router browserHistory.listen unlisten

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history, react-router-v4

How can I unlisten to that route?
My function "execute" keeps running one Im cliking on links

```js
const unlisten = browserHistory.listen(unlis);
```

function handleUrl(location) {
    const newPath = location.pathname;
    if (!newPath.includes(`${id})`)) {
      execute();
      unlisten(window.location);
    }
    else unlisten(window.location);
  browserHistory.listen(handleUrl);
  handleUrl(window.location);

Ive tried to do:

```js
  browserHistory.push(`/search/${id}');

  const unlisten = browserHistory.listen(location);

  function handleUrl(location) {
    const newPath = location.pathname;
    if (!newPath.includes(`${id})`) {
      execute();
      unlisten(window.location);
    else unliste;
  browserHistory.listen(handleUrl);
  handleUrl(window.location);
```

but no luck

Comment: I'm using react-router 3.0 and cannot change it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find out how to fix it

```js
  let unlisten;
  function handleUrl(location) {
    const newPath = location.pathname;
    if (!newPath.includes(`${id})`)) {
      execute();
      unlisten();
    }
  unlisten = browserHistory.listen(handleUrl);
  handleUrl(window.location);
}
```